# Not able to skip the scenarios in story while extending SerenityStories

Tags: jbehave, serenity-bdd

While creating new scenarios I only want to test the scenario I am currently working with. For this purpose I want to use the Meta: @skip tag before my scenarios. As I found out I have to use the embedder to configure the used meta tags, so I tried:

```
configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));
```

but actually this still has no effect on my test scenarios

But now I get the message  [pool-1-thread-1] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST IGNORED but the scenario is still executed. Only in the result page I get the info that this scenario is ignored (but still executed). Is there a way to SKIP the scenario so it won't run?

Here is my scenario description Meta: @skip Given something When something Then something

Answer (score 0):

Try with the latest version of serenity-bdd since there is an implementation which is related to your query. refer [this](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/95).